# How to have two columns with the same field but different values in a GridView

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm currently doing a project in ASP.NET/C# on where I have a GridView which gets two types of data from two different tables, ID and Initials.

The table itself must be sort of like this:

---

UNIT 1

ID - INITIALS

---

And a Column right next to it:

---

UNIT 2

ID - INITIALS

---

The IDs are being called from Table 2, while the INITIALS are being called from Table 1. Each ID has it's own INITIALS, but my problem is that, since the INITIALS are being called twice, they repeat themselves on the following and previous Columns, as seen [here](https://s21.postimg.org/4vvl79y0n/Capturar.png).

My current code (ASPX):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass= "table table-hover table-bordered" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="4" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" OnPageIndexChanged="SearchByTagButton_Click" Style="max-width:75%;" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UNIDADE" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#B70700" HeaderStyle-Width="34%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unidade")%>
                            -
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sigUnidade")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UNIDADE APOIADA" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#B70700" HeaderStyle-Width="34%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unidadeApoiada")%>
                            -
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sigUnidade")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

And C#:

```
SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();    
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ts.unidade, u.sigUnidade FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN UNIDADES u on u.unidade = ts.unidade WHERE '%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%' IS NULL OR LEN('%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%') = 0 OR (ts.unidade='%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%') OR ts.unidade LIKE '%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%'", conn);
    da.Fill(ds1);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ts.unidadeApoiada, u.sigUnidade FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN UNIDADES u on u.unidade = ts.unidadeApoiada WHERE '%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%' IS NULL OR LEN('%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%') = 0 OR (ts.unidadeApoiada='%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%') OR ts.unidadeApoiada LIKE '%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%'", conn);
    da.Fill(ds2);
    ds1.Merge(ds2);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

I basically join two DataSets, one for each SQL Query, as I found it the only way to join both queries to get both ID's (they're different, as in they're all a "main ID" in Table 1, but in Table 2 they can also be "sub ID's".

I tried to explain my best, but would like my table to be formatted as ID - INITIALS without any repetitions. If I could get any help, I'd be really appreciated.

Comment: If 2 datasets do not have any relationships, then create 1 gridview for each column?

Comment: First of all you must use parameters in query and not concatenation: `OR (ts.unidade='%" + txtCodigoSearch.Text + "%')` becomes `OR ts.unidate = @myParameter`

Comment: Now the question is why two unidades are on the same line? I think for unidade.id, so maybe you can do only one query and have 3 template fields:sigUnidade,  unidade, unidadeApoiada.

Comment: @TriV that was my thought initially, the person who gave me the task wants it all in one gridview.

Comment: @Emanuele sorry, I didn't understand the first part. Two unidades on the same line? My main issue is just getting the Initials (sigUnidade) for both unidade and unidadeApoiada, and not have them repeating.

Comment: Missing something... Either data are not related so you have bind two gridviews, or data are related and you have to find the relation. What is represented in one row? The structure is T_SECRETARIAS(unidade, unidadeApoiada), UNIDADES(unidade) so i think a single row represents a secretaria (=department).

Comment: @Emanuele First table (unidades), is as followed UNIDADES(unidade, sigUnidade) and second table (t_secretarias) is T_SECRETARIAS(unidade, unidadeApoiada). Basically, both unidade and unidadeApoiada in the second table are getting the values from unidade in the first table, and I need to get the sigUnidade of both, thus needing to get it from the first table. I don't know if you understand, trying my best to explain but English isn't my first language and my brain is already broken from trying many times.

Comment: So you can change the query: da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ts.unidade, ts.unidadeApoiada, u1.sigUnidade as sigUnidade1, u2.sigUnidade as sigUnidade2   FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN UNIDADES u1 on u1.unidade = ts.unidade INNER JOIN UNIDADES u2 on u2.unidade = ts.unidadeApoiada WHERE...   If data are not related, you can use union, removing in both cases the second query and the merge instruction. @J.Mestre

Comment: @Emanuele you're a savior! Really well explained and I managed to do it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from comments, you can have the following code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet(); 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ts.unidade, ts.unidadeApoiada, u1.sigUnidade as sigUnidade1, u2.sigUnidade as sigUnidade2 FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN UNIDADES u1 on u1.unidade = ts.unidade INNER JOIN UNIDADES u2 on u2.unidade = ts.unidadeApoiada WHERE....", conn);
da.Fill(ds1);
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and in aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UNIDADE">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unidade")%>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sigUnidade1")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UNIDADE APOIADA">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unidadeApoiada")%>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sigUnidade2")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using just one query with UNION .
So you would have 
SELECT ts.unidade  , u.sigUnidade FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN UNIDADES ..
UNION
SELECT ts.unidadeApoiada as unidas, u.sigUnidade FROM T_SECRETARIAS ts INNER JOIN ...

You have to use the same name for the output on both Queries

Comment: Ends up saying "System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'unidadeApoiada'."

Comment: This solution is valid if data are not related. The error you have derive from aspx, you have to change unidadeApoiada in unidade.

Answer (score 0):

You just create one column like phone number, it's the perfect example for your question I think. I am also trying to resolve these type of errors. That's why I am telling you use this code. I hope it's useful for you. It's sample code to merge multiple textbox values into a singe cell in gridview.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RVM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=rvm;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=rvmbecse");
    string str = "insert into multext values('"+TextBox1.Text +" , " + TextBox2.Text + "')";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str,con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //Response.Write("<script>alert('HI RVM Data inserted Successfully')</script>");
}
```